# Android click listener

Tags: android, onclicklistener

java i am having trouble with the switch statement part of the code. it doesn't seem to take me to the page which is been clicked on. Only the dashboard shows and each layout has already been created help please

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SubMenu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

public class home extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Defining Variables
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        // Initializing Toolbar and setting it as the actionbar
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //Initializing NavigationView
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

        //Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {


                //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
                if (menuItem.isChecked()) menuItem.setChecked(false);
                else menuItem.setChecked(true);

                //Closing drawer on item click
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {


                    //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
                    case R.id.dashboard:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inbox Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Dashboard fragment = new Dashboard();
                        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        return true;

                    // For rest of the options we just show a toast on click

                    case R.id.profile:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Profile Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         new Profile();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.logs:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logs Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        new Logs();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.statements:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Statements Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        new Statements();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.timeline:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TImeline Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        new Timeline();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.settings:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Settings Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        new Settings();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.logout:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logout Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    default:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Somethings Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;

                }
            }
        });

        // Initializing Drawer Layout and ActionBarToggle
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank

                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };

        //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

        //calling sync state is necessay or else your hamburger icon wont show up
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();


        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "home Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://www.arkounting.com.ng.finark/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "home Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://www.arkounting.com.ng.finark/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
        client.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: Consolidate this into the code related to the problem, give an example of the incorrect output, and show any errors you've encountered

Comment: actually no errors are shown. it just doesnt direct me to the layout required for each item

Answer (score 1):

I think this is how your switch statement should look like:

```
switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
                Fragment fragment = null;
                case R.id.dashboard:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inbox Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    fragment = new Dashboard();
                    break;
                case R.id.profile:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Profile Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    fragment = new Profile();
                    break;
                case R.id.logs:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logs Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    fragment = new Logs();
                    return true;
                case R.id.statements:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Statements Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    fragment = new Statements();
                    break;
                case R.id.timeline:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TImeline Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    fragment = new Timeline();
                    break;
                case R.id.settings:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Settings Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    fragment = new Settings();
                    return true;
                case R.id.logout:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logout Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                default:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Somethings Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                if (fragment != null) {
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    return true;
                } else {
                   return true;  
                }

            }
```